# python-gnupg search_keys() returns different result when run as root

Tags: linux, python, gnupg

I have a python script that needs to be run as root (to access framebuffer on a raspberry pi with a [small touchscreen](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1601)). This script also needs to search for keys on a keyserver. To achieve this, I am using the function `search_keys()` from [python-gnupg](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#searching-for-keys).

The following script works fine when I execute it with `python gpg_test.py`:

```
import gnupg

gpg= gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/pi/.gnupg")
keyserver= "pool.sks-keyservers.net"
search_string= "testuser@example.com"
print gpg.search_keys(search_string, keyserver)
```

This prints a list containing a few keys.

However, if I run the same script with `sudo python gpg_test.py`, I just get an empty list.
Does someone know the reason for this behaviour? And maybe a solution to get it working when run as root?

---

Edit: I looked at the source of python-gnupg and found that the result of `search_keys()` includes the stderr output of the underlying pgp call. Assigning the result of search_keys() to a variable `result` and calling `print result.stderr` prints the following:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir `/home/pi/.gnupg'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver search failed: general error
```

So it seems to me, the problem is that I am trying to access the pgp homedir of a different user (`pi` instead of `root`).

---

Edit: Changing the owner of `/home/pi/.gnupg` to root fixed it, but that seems like an awful "solution". And it also forces me to use `sudo gpg ...` instead of `gpg ...` when I want to use gpg from the command line. So I'm still curious about better solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here, just in case somebody else has a similar problem.

My solution was to initialize python-gnupg with a new homedir. That new homedir now belongs to the user `root` because the script is run as root.

That way, everything the script does is independent from the gpg installation I access when typoing `gpg [command]` in the terminal. And there are no more errors when searching keyservers.

So changing the above python code to this does the job:

```
import gnupg

gpg= gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/pi/gnupg_myscript")
keyserver= "pool.sks-keyservers.net"
search_string= "testuser@example.com"
print gpg.search_keys(search_string, keyserver)
```